# MySql giving me incorrect date after adding same date with JDBC

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC to add some rows to my DB and they have a date aspect to it.

The GMT String for the date I'm adding in the commit is

> 11 Jan 2014 05:00:00 GMT

but when I get it back I'm getting this:

> 11 Jan 2014 04:00:00 GMT

I'm 1 hour ahead of my server and this might be part of the problem. I tried using datetime and timestamp but none of these solved my problem.

my JDBC query looks like this: (it's in Scala)

```
        val statement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `listings`(`track_id`, `date`, `position`) VALUES (?,?,?)");
        statement.setInt(1, trackId);
        statement.setDate(2,trackListing.date);
        statement.setInt(3, trackListing.position);
        statement.execute();
```

Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: What type of field is `date`? Is it DATETIME or TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Right now it's timestamp.

Comment: The timestamp field converts to the session timezone when you read from it, check the result of `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;` the fact that the GMT is included in the date when you set it does confuse me a little tho. If the same connection is used for reading and writing there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Yes, I am sending from here, to a server with a -1 hour diff from me, then reading it again from the same place.

This is what I got from your query: 

`+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that by changing setDate and getDate to setTimestamp and getTimestamp I could fix it. I ended up just wrapping the timestamps to dates to maintain compatiblity, using:

```
   new java.sql.Date(rs.getTimestamp("date").getTime());
```

Hope this helps someone else with the same problem in the future.